# Is there a way to do a drop-shadow but with solid color?

Tags: css, outline, dropshadow

I want to basically have an outline that strokes around my .png image. `drop-shadow` property does almost that, but if you want an outline, you need to set offsets to 0, and non-zero blur radius. Something like this:

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px red);
```

So in full example like this:

```
<div style="background: url(cubes.png); width: 400px; height: 300px; background-size: cover; filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px red)"></div>
```

with the `cubes.png` being this image:[image], so it yields this: [image]

I want something like that drop shadow, but basically remove any transparency created by the blur, so it would create an outline that strokes the .png.

Css `outline` draws line around the element border, which I don't want either.

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Wont a regular `border` with `box-sizing: content-box;` be enough?

Comment: I am not making myself clear. I will update the question with images.

Comment: share the real transparent image so we can give you answers

Comment: Could you make it a [mre] with the example images?

Comment: Sorry for initial low quality question. I properly updated the question and I hope I am finally making myself clear.